# Compare URLs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, url

Suppose I have two URLs:

http://foo.com/homepage.html

AND

https://foo.com/homepage.html?ref=topnav&bar=1

Is there any easy way (or some easy external library) that I can use to check if two URLs are the same EXCLUDING http/https and EXCLUDING any arguments?

For example, the above two urls would be equivalent.

Comment: Applying a regex might solve your problem easily. '.*://(.*?)/' should work to grab the base url. There is probably a ruby library to extract base URLs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) and compare paths:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("https://foo.com/homepage.html/ref=topnav?bar=1")
#=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000000b14880
      https://foo.com/homepage.html/ref=topnav?bar=1>

uri.path
#=> "/homepage.html"

uri.host
#=> "foo.com"
```

There are other methods on `URI` to decompose a URI in different ways. So you can write a method to compare based on as many such ways as you want.

Comment: I agree. Comparing the paths would be a good way to check this.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but uri.path seems to keep the /ref=topnav portion...Is there anyway to get rid of this?

Comment: @Nosrettap, /ref=topnav is part of the path, not a parameter. If you want to strip that off you'll need some custom coding, e.g. strip off the end of the uri if it matches that pattern.